Strongswan Server install on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS server - vici not found
I'm trying to set up a strongswan sever on Server 24.04.1.
Per their install page, to use the vici protocol:

When installing the strongswan metapackage, the legacy daemon and configuration backend are installed. To use swanctl/vici instead,
install the charon-systemd and strongswan-swanctl packages and remove
both the strongswan-starter and strongswan-charon packages. Make sure
you only have either the charon-systemd or the strongswan-starter
package installed (or at least disable one of the systemd units they
install, which are strongswan.service and strongswan-starter.service,
respectively).

The strongswan packages I have installed are:

$ apt search strongswan Sorting... Done Full Text Search... Done
charon-cmd/noble 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64   standalone IPsec client
charon-systemd/noble,now 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
strongSwan IPsec client, systemd support
libcharon-extauth-plugins/noble,now 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
strongSwan charon library (extended authentication plugins)
libcharon-extra-plugins/noble,now 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
strongSwan charon library (extra plugins)
libstrongswan/noble,now 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
strongSwan utility and crypto library
libstrongswan-extra-plugins/noble,now 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64
[installed]   strongSwan utility and crypto library (extra plugins)
libstrongswan-standard-plugins/noble,now 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64
[installed,automatic]   strongSwan utility and crypto library
(standard plugins)
network-manager-strongswan/noble 1.6.0-3build2 amd64   network
management framework (strongSwan plugin)
strongswan/noble 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 all   IPsec VPN solution metapackage
strongswan-charon/noble 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64 [residual-config]
strongSwan Internet Key Exchange daemon
strongswan-libcharon/noble,now 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64
[installed,automatic]   strongSwan charon library
strongswan-nm/noble 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64   strongSwan plugin to
interact with NetworkManager
strongswan-pki/noble 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64 [residual-config]
strongSwan IPsec client, pki command
strongswan-starter/noble 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64 [residual-config]
strongSwan daemon starter and configuration file parser
strongswan-swanctl/noble,now 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
strongSwan IPsec client, swanctl command

When I attempt to use swanctl, I get the following error:
$ swanctl --stats connecting to 'unix:///var/run/charon.vici' failed: No such file or directory Error: connecting to 'default' URI failed: No such file or directory strongSwan 5.9.11 swanctl
Checking Syslog I see the below messages and errors:
2024-09-01T00:03:04.294378-04:00 huginn kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1725163384.292:213): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" class="file" profile="/usr/sbin/charon-systemd" name="/usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10.5.0" pid=23072 comm="charon-systemd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2024-09-01T00:03:04.294395-04:00 huginn kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1725163384.292:214): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_mmap" class="file" profile="/usr/sbin/charon-systemd" name="/usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10.5.0" pid=23072 comm="charon-systemd" requested_mask="rm" denied_mask="rm" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2024-09-01T00:03:04.300204-04:00 huginn charon-systemd[23072]: using '/sbin/resolvconf' to install DNS servers
2024-09-01T00:03:04.300684-04:00 huginn charon-systemd[23072]: feature CUSTOM:libcharon in critical plugin 'charon-systemd' has unmet dependency: NONCE_GEN
2024-09-01T00:03:04.300728-04:00 huginn charon-systemd[23072]: feature CUSTOM:libcharon-receiver in critical plugin 'charon-systemd' has unmet dependency: HASHER:HASH_SHA1
2024-09-01T00:03:04.300757-04:00 huginn charon-systemd[23072]: feature CUSTOM:libcharon-sa-managers in critical plugin 'charon-systemd' has unmet dependency: HASHER:HASH_SHA1
2024-09-01T00:03:04.308871-04:00 huginn charon-systemd[23072]: failed to load 3 critical plugin features

I'm somewhat at a loss with regard to the packages in the repos.
Do the packages not install the vici package and all the parts? or are they missing things?
Do I just need to build from source? What am I missing?

The IKE daemon fails to start because it doesn't have a SHA-1 implementation loaded, which is very weird. Did you configure specific plugin load instructions in strongswan.conf or a file it includes?
